What happens to the amplitude when a spring is compressed?
Say there's a spring lying on a horizontal table, with one end attached to a wall (say the left end) and it is in it's natural length. Now I compress the spring from the right end, and leave it. So will the amplitude of this spring be equal to how much I compressed it or will it go beyond the point where it's natural length lay earlier? Which is the mean point and what are the extremities?
Also, how do I calculate the amplitude?

In the case of an ideal spring, this situation sets up a simple harmonic oscillator with an amplitude equal to the distance you compressed the spring by.  Note that the amplitude being equal to that compression distance means that it will surpass its natural length after you release the spring. It will extend beyond that point until it is stretched to the same offset by which you had previously compressed it. As such, the "mean point" (which I interpret to mean the point half-way between the extrema of motion) is the natural length of the spring, and the extrema will be at $x_0\pm A$ for a natural length $x_0$ and amplitude $A$ set by your initial compression.

After reading ur explanation I realised I framed one of the sentences incorrectly but you still managed to answer the doubt I had in my mind, thank you so much

Hey riley! I have another doubt regarding this. Let's say the mass is suspended from a spring on the ceiling. The spring is elongated by x for the mass to reach equilibrium. Now I pull the mass downwards by y and leave it. So which becomes the amplitude here? x or y?

@android Gravity shifts the equilibrium position, but then you can apply the same logic from my answer above. The displacement from the eq. pos. when you release the mass from rest will become the amplitude of oscillations. So here it is $y$.
